# Inner joins performance

Tags: oracle, inner-join, sqlperformance

SQL statement:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(A,10)*/
    B.USER_ID, B.ACCT_ID, ITEM_ID, SUMFEE_C, SUMFEE_P, 
    USER_BEGIN_DATE, USER_END_DATE
FROM   
    TS_B_USER_RATEFEE_03 A, DH_ROUTE_6_OPTIONAL PARTITION(PAR_DH_ROUTE6_4) B
WHERE  
    A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
ORDER BY 
    B.ACCT_ID, B.USER_ID;
```

[image]
table A has index on `user_id`

How to improve inner joins performance with the same column?

Comment: @muraleekrishna thanks

Comment: Is there a real performance problem, or do you just not like seeing the words "TABLE ACCESS FULL" in the plan, as highlighted?  If these are large tables, as it appears they are, and if you really want all matching rows from both, then full scans and has joins are probably the best plan.

Comment: @TonyAndrews is right, doing a full scan on the table allows oracle to retrieve data in chunks, and therefore can often yield better results than index scans. If you are looking to improve anything about the following query, you can start with rewriting the join in an explicit form, since implicit joins are obsolete.

Comment: @Tony Andrews  I am not sure this explain plan is the best.Is there a better sql statement,because table A has 0.2 billion data,but table B has 1.2 million data.

Comment: @Yaron Idan implicit joins has the same explain plan with the explicit joins.Implicit joins query data faster than explicit joins on oracle 11g.

Comment: How can two queries with the same explain plan perform differently from one another? I only suggested changing your sybtax for readability purposes and since its oracle's advised best practice, but do what you like.

Comment: What is the purpose of this query - what are you going to do with all the results?  If displaying them for a user to page through then a FIRST_ROWS hint could be helpful, to get the first rows faster (while taking a lot longer to get all rows).

Comment: @Tony Andrews I want to query all the data to load to redis

Comment: OK, so you want to load up Redis's memory with **all** of the millions of rows that this query will return?  In that case you must expect to wait a while for this to happen.  Are you sure it's a good idea?

Comment: Just read this (http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/take-advantage-of-redis-adding-it-to-your-stack.html) where it says "Also for some other kind of applications Redis may not be the right database: for instance a Redis data set can't be bigger than available memory, so if you have some big data application and a mostly-reads access pattern, Redis is not the right pick." #justsaying!

Comment: @Tony Andrews thanks.So i have to wait to query all the data.Thanks for the url. I appreciate it.